# Are the Fibonacci numbers' prevalence in nature due to confirmation bias?

Tags: statistics, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci numbers are frequently found in nature, such as in the petals of flowers or the shape of pinecones.

But are the numbers actually any more prevalent than other numbers? Could it all be because of confirmation bias?

*Is there any research that shows that the Fibonacci numbers occur in nature to a statistically significant extent?*

Comment: It's all those [wascally wabbits](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WZZVEzNzt8)...

Comment: Today, I computed the degree of convexity of a 5-sided star.  It came out to be the inverse of the Golden Ratio; the Golden Ratio is the limit of the ratio of the Fibonacci numbers.  Is this nature?  Maybe not quite, but these numbers (and the Golden Ratio) show up periodically.

Comment: Ah, but the Golden Ratio is the limit of the ratio of every sequence formed by adding the previous two numbers. The Golden Ratio may be significantly prevalent, but are any of those sequences significantly prevalent? I don't know, but I hope someone does :)

Comment: Or, here's an even better question: *Is the Fibonacci numbers' absence in nature due to infirmation bias?* ;-)

Comment: prevalence = statistical significance?

Answer (score 1):

As stated, your hypothesis is too vague. In order to make inferences, you need to know what population you are analyzing. Is it the population of all enumerable phenomena? How would one even design a sampling strategy? Such things cannot be done for questions like this unless you know how to measure such a thing. I seriously doubt that you will find a paper to decide your question one way or another.

As for confirmation bias: The world is filled with numbers. However, as humans we are pattern seekers, so we find interest and novelty in phenomena that satisfy our aesthetic sense of order and pattern. The Fibonacci numbers are such a case. We take notice when such a sequence is present in nature, but ignore the vast (I'd say essentially infinite) number of occurrences when such patterns are a absent, because they are uninteresting.

So yes, our preoccupation with noticing interesting patterns in "unstructured" nature is definitely a case of confirmation bias, just like when you run into a friend in a random city and then ask "what are the odds of that?"

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @curiousdannii my apologies...I was addressing a related point...poorly. I've revised my response to directly address your question about statistically confirming the "significance" of the Fibbonacci numbers.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good edit.